# My link disappears on mouseover

Tags: html, wordpress, themes

On my site - http://goo.gl/Vqsqgi - for some reason on my navbar when you mouseover the "Our Packages" button, the text disappears.

I've checked the CSS and there doesnt appear to be any rogue tags etc, I've made sure it isnt set to the same colour (should turn white, not green).

I've spent about an hour looking and I cannot see it!

Can anyone spot anything I've missed please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `:before` selector on `:hover`, it overlaps the text.

**EDIT:**

change in your CSS

```
.desktop ul.art-hmenu>li.ext>a:hover,
.desktop ul.art-hmenu>li.ext:hover>a,
.desktop ul.art-hmenu>li.ext:hover>a.active{
       background: #009966; /*this line is changed*/
       /* default padding + border size */
       padding: 0 17px 0 17px;
       /* margin for shadow */
       margin: -0 -0 0 -0;
       overflow: hidden;
       position: relative;
       border: none;
       border-radius: 0;
       box-shadow: none;
       color: #FFFFFF;
}

.desktop ul.art-hmenu>li.ext>a:hover:before,
.desktop ul.art-hmenu>li.ext:hover>a:before,
.desktop ul.art-hmenu>li.ext:hover>a.active:before{
       position: absolute;
       /*content: '';*/ /*this line is changed*/
       /* top, right, left - for shadow */
       top: 0;
       right: 0;
       left: 0;
       /* border + shadow */
       bottom: -1px;
       background: #009966;
       border: 1px Dotted rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.9);
       border-top-left-radius: 0;
       border-top-right-radius: 0;
       box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

}
```

Comment: Hey,
@Ramis - I've just looked but cannot see where it overlaps :s

Can you give me the code to check/remove please?

http://pastebin.com/u5ymPXUf

Comment: Hey @Ramis,
I changed as you suggested but it still fails to show :(